# How to hide pivotable editor box permanently in Google spreadsheet?

Tags: spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

when I'm using with my data in pivot table data, the pivot table editor window comes again n again after clicking on close icon also. So please suggest how to turn it off permanently.

Comment: Just for clarification, do you want the UI to not appear? This seems like a not possible. 
You could try to protect the [sheet](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1218656?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).

Answer (score 5):

Install the Stylebot extension and override CSS with

```css
.waffle-pivot-sidebar {display:none}
```

Toggle the editor off/on with just 2 mouse clicks.

Comment: This is very good and easy to set up! Cheers mate

Comment: Now it's called `.waffle-pivot-table-edit-pill`.  So the snippet is `.waffle-pivot-table-edit-pill {display: none}`

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible at this point. You can keep checking on the [ticket](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/59918141?hl=en). All you can do for now is send them feedback using the form under `Help/Help Sheets Improve`.

Answer (score 0):

open your conditional formatting window it is much better than pivot table editor and small in size, it also prevent pivot table to pop up again and again that's the only reliable solution till now I have found. hope this going to helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

A really silly workaround is to create a separate sheet where each cell points to the sheet with the pivot table in it. It looks ugly but at least the side window does keep popping open. Open to other ideas though.

Answer (score 0):

Building on top of another idea (New1), you could open the *Pivot table Editor*, *Conditional formatting* or *Named ranges* side window and then make the browser window bigger than your screen. When you alight the left side of the window to the screen the editor window says out of sight hidden. Then you can click your data without the annoying window attacking you.

Home this helps until someone of google comes out with a setting to keep it hidden.